# spring integration SFTP login acess use public keys instead of private key?

Tags: spring, spring-integration

as title mentioned, could spring integration SFTP acess login with public key?
in spring integration document, it supply configuration with private like this

```
<beans:bean id="sftpSessionFactory"
class="org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.DefaultSftpSessionFactory">
<beans:property name="host" value="localhost"/>
<beans:property name="privateKey" value="classpath:META-INF/keys/sftpTest"/>
<beans:property name="privateKeyPassphrase" value="springIntegration"/>
<beans:property name="port" value="22"/>
<beans:property name="user" value="kermit"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

No; it doesn't work that way - read up on public/private key authentication.

The server has the public key and you never, never, share the private key.

This configuration doesn't mean the private key is "sent" to the server, it is simply used by the handshake locally to make sure that a client with this private key is allowed to access the server (because the server has the corresponding public key).